# Некорректная верстка на TCL 10SE Android 10

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Проблема: на смартфоне TCL 10SE (а также на некоторых других китайских) некорректно отображаются вьюхи: очень маленькие текст и иконки.
Размер иконок указан в dp, текста  - в sp.
Да и разрешение экрана у данного TCL - 1600x720, то есть меньше чем у второго примера с корректными размерами вьюх.
Также я проверил не воспринимает ли приложение этот телефон как планшет - нет, если создать две отдельные верстки для планшета и смартфона он использует именно ту, что для смартфона.

Другие приложения на этом смартфоне выглядят нормально, значит где-то в приложении недочет, но в то же время на всех остальных устройствах приложение выглядит корректно.
На вложенных скринах сверху - как выглядит верстка на TCL 10SE, снизу - как на остальных смартфонах.

Если кто-то сталкивался с подобным, буду благодарен за любые пути решения.

[image: incorrect]
[image: correct]

Разметка элемента списка, если нужно:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_settings_image"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_friends_icon"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding16"
        app:tint="@color/colorOmega"
        android:tag="iv_omega"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_settings_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Профиль"
        style="@style/Regular18Black"
        android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/iv_arrow"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_settings_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_arrow"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_left"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Вот что показывают два разных приложения DPI-checker-а, с помощью которых я проверяю DPI экрана устройства, где баг воспроизводится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чего вы ждете , чуда? гадалки в отпуске. Покажите xml разметку, второе - какой шрифт установлен в настройках телефона посмотрите, возможно уменьшенный

Comment: Добавил верстку элементов списка

Comment: Cтиль еще покажитеб и в самой мобиле вероято уменьшены шрифты?